# Получить дату дня в неделе

Tags: laravel, carbon

Возможно ли в Carbon получить дату зная номер недели в году, год и день недели ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
  $date->setISODate($year,$week);
  $date->addDays($dayNumber);
```

Как то так